\againframe increases frame number independent of overlay specification
I suppose this behavior is intended, nevertheless, the existence of commands such as \insertoverlaynumber suggest to me that an overlay-aware frame counter could be useful. While one could decrement that TeX counter in-place with, for example,
\makeatletter
\global\advance\c@framenumber by-1\relax
\makeatother

I found the following more concise workaround helpful:
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand<>\myagainframe[1]{\only#2{\againframe#2{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\frame[label=a]{Test: \inserttotalframenumber}
\againframe<beamer:0>{a}       %  <== increases \c@framenumber
\myagainframe<beamer:0>{a}     %  <== doesn't, hence, 2 instead of 3
\end{document}

Note that the use of \only outside frames is tricky and it restricts the overlay specs and the number of slides in a particular mode. It does not work well. One can work with \mode instead but that requires adding a second argument. Hence, are there any better solutions, perhaps, even without the need to introduce an extra command?
I tried to find some, but what I found are the discussions here and here, which unfortunately go into slightly different directions.

To quote the beamer user guide:

Frames which are hidden with <0> behave like the noframenumbering option and will not be counted for the number of frames (this only applies if no mode is specified, e.g. not for <all:0>).

This means, you can simply hide the frame from all modes and it won't increase the frame number:
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=a]
  Test: \inserttotalframenumber
\end{frame}

\againframe<0>{a}

\end{document}


Thanks, @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, for pointing to the manual. This would definitely solve my problem. Unfortunately, I am using several modes with many of those frames, beamer, handout, presentation, and at times article. Many frames need to be hidden in a mode-specific manner, otherwise, I'm usually just commenting them out.
